# How to convert Mono<List<T>> to Stream<T>?

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-webflux

I have a code that uses WebClient to create a `Mono<List<T>>` from a Json array result.  The bodyToMono method returns a `Mono<List<T>` object, which I subscribe to and then get a `parallelStream`

```
    final WebClient client = WebClient.create(daemonEndpoint);
    client.get()
        .uri("/services?label=com.docker.stack.namespace")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
        })
        .subscribe(services -> services.parallelStream()
            .map(e -> {
                final String id = (String) e.get("ID");
```

What I want to know is whether there is a solution that removes that subscribe part.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with reactor you can't transform your Mono to Stream without blocking call, it can be done as follow:

```
Stream<T> stream = yourMono<T>.map(it -> it.parallelStream()).block()
```

Another way just process it in reactive approach *(note, anyway someone have to subscribe to your publisher, it can't be done by itself)*:

```
yourMono<T>.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
           .flatMap(it -> {
              //there goes your <Map<String, Object>>
           });
```

Comment: The `flatMap` caused issues because it had to create a publisher for me.  I changed it to `map` and the other listener stopped working so maybe that's why you chose `flatMap`